# Extending Area to full width of Chart with Months on x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have this chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/lamarant/KTksk/

As you can see, there is space on the left and right side of the two plotted areas. How do I force the plotted areas to take the full width of the chart?

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            plotBackgroundColor: '#00B417'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov'],
.....
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing these as area series and not using y-axis plotbands? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands

Comment: yes..the "bands" may not always be horizontal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a min/max value on the xaxis:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov'],
        endOnTick: false,
        startOnTick: false,
        min: 0.5,
        max: 7.5
    },
```

Update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTksk/6/).

Comment: Thanks. This works. I understand the 0.5 value for the Min, but why 7.5 for the Max? There are 9 data points. Why wouldn't the Max be 8.5?

Comment: sorry...this doesn't work when there are two data points: http://jsfiddle.net/lamarant/KTksk/

Comment: Yeah, it just doesn't want to work with 2 categories.  I fudged it by setting an inner null:  http://jsfiddle.net/KTksk/11/

Answer (score 0):

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement

```
plotOptions.series.pointPlacement = "on"
```

https://codepen.io/Artemeey/pen/QWBoVMo

Comment: Artemeey, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).